# redirecting in wordpress blog in my laravel app running on apache server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, laravel

*I have a laravel site*. I am **trying to integrate a wordpress blog at `mysitename.com/blog`**. I have ***placed*** the contents of wordpress blog in a **folder named** **'blog'** **in the 'public' directory**.

I have created the database for wordpress and everything else works fine. But, while testing, *when I try to access **'localhost/mylaravelsitename/public/blog/index.php'***, **it redirects me to 'localhost/blog'**. I **can't understand why**!

*I tried turning the redirect engine **OFF** in '.htaccess' file in the 'public' directory and then restarted apache but it still does the same*.

Please guide me.

Comment: That's probably what it should be doing. To run Laravel properly you should either set up a virtual host (vhost) or cd into your directory using command/terminal and then use "php artisan serve" which will create a local php server. You can then go to localhost:8000 to view your website.

Comment: create a virtual host to site.

Comment: @CheckeredMichael But I don't want it to redirect. What should be done for that?

Comment: @Hemc Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `Alias` feature of apache to overcome this problem. I added an alias for `'/blog'` in my virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep setup Laravel using a virtualhost and make sure it works correctly.  Then I would install Wordpress in an entirely separate location and use an alias to send traffic to it.  For example, suppose your Wordpress folder is:

```
/var/www/wordpress/
```

You could simply add the following to your apache/vhosts config:

```
Alias /blog /var/www/wordpress/
```

You can also do a virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    ServerName www.yoursite.com/blog
    <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work. I am still facing the same problem.